# What time format is used in "1468777498"?

Tags: php, json

I have API to check connected phone to smsgateway.me.
This is my API json response

```
{"success":true,"result":{"id":"24678","name":"Device 24678","make":"Samsung","model":"GT-S7392","number":"",
"provider":"Telenor PK","country":"pk","connection_type":"2G","battery":"14","signal":"100","wifi":"1",
"lat":"0","lng":"0","last_seen":1468777498,"created_at":false}}
```

Here is `"last_seen":1468777498,"`, but what is type of this time?

How can i know that what is time this or can i decode/translate it? Also I want to extract `last_seen` into a PHP string with simple format like

```
$last_seen =  "2 minutes 30 seconds ago';
```

Comment: If the service documentation doesn't tell you then the service is crap.

Comment: [timestamp](http://www.epochconverter.com/) maybe?

Comment: That is a Unix timestamp.  Pass it as the second parameter to `date()`, as in `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', '1468777498')` to convert it to some other string format.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Maybe, but a UNIX timestamp is pretty ubiquitous as a date/time value format.

Comment: This one may be better than the other one I linked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php